# laravel - how to set relation with hasManyThrough?

Tags: laravel

I have problem with relation of laravel in this case.

One event has many event dates.

One event date has many tickets.

One ticket has many slots. User will book slot and save in booking table.

How can i get list of event dates have list of tickets and total booking of every ticket ?

In Event model i has :

```
return $this->hasMany('App\EventTicket', 'event_date_id');
```

Please help me improve it to get right data ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) How can I get list of event dates to have list of tickets?

you can make `hasManyThrough` relation for that. In **EventDates** model make relation as `tickes` with `hasManyThrough`.

Now through event dates, you will get all the tickets for that day.

2) total booking of every ticket

after make `hasManyThrough` you can use `withCount('tickes')` with this, you'll get the booking total count.